# Swift: App crashing with fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked at many others with the same error (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value?) here on Stack but I don't understand what may be equal to nil in my scenario because there is so much going on in the crashing line.

The actual exception is "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, sub code= 0x0" and it crashes on the line indicated below. I'm not sure if the Bool, `plays` or `spot` is equal to nil. Also this same error occurs on 3 other lines when i click down the bars under Thread 1.

These subsequent lines all involve the `isOccupied` function, which in turn involve that one line. I'm thinking that I solve this first error the others will be solved.

The code block where plays is introduced:

```
    var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
    var done = false
    var aiDeciding = false
```

And where error is:

```
func isOccupied(spot:Int)->(Bool) {
        return Bool(plays[spot]!) //ERROR LINE
    }
```

Changed to this:

```
func isOccupied(spot:Int)->(Bool) {
        if plays != nil {
        return Bool(plays[spot]!)
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and examine the variables in the debugger?  Break the line into several lines?

Answer (score 3):

A `Dictionary`'s subscript function will return an `Optional` (in this case `Int?`) regardless of the key type.  This is because you may be requesting a key that doesn't exist. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_180):

> Because it is possible to request a key for which no value exists, a
>   dictionary’s subscript returns an optional value of the dictionary’s
>   value type.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
func isOccupied(spot: Int) -> Bool {
    if let doesPlay = plays[spot] {
        return Bool(doesPlay)
    } else {
        return false // assuming that's a sane default
    }
}
```

Comment: So I changed the isOccupied function to the above (look in my original question) and now Im getting the same exception on the `class AppDelegate` line of the App Delegate file. What does that mean?

Comment: The problem isn't with plays being nil, the problem is with what's returned from plays[sport].  That's why I'm doing let doesPlay = ... and not just checking if plays is nil first.

Comment: So I don't have a variable in my func like your doesPlay so how can I do what you are suggesting? Should I just create a variable?

Comment: The `let doesPlay = plays[sport]` part is creating `doesPlay` variable. See the section on "Optional Binding" in the [language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_478).

Comment: Sorry yeah I realized that seconds after I commented. So I did that and it fixed the exception, except for the part that I returned in the else part doesn't make any sense to the rest of the code, so the app doesn't work. Can you take a look at the new question I posted?